# Reading all bytes from multiple files

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am trying to read multiple binary files using ReadAllBytesAsync.  Why is the version with Task.Run(), shown below, almost twice as fast as the one without.  I was expecting the ReadAll1 method being the equivalent as ReadAll2.

test2.bin is a duplicate of test1.bin (each is approximately 100 MB)

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ReadAll1 | 81.57 ms | 1.385 ms | 1.942 ms | 199.37 MB |
| ReadAll2 | 44.55 ms | 1.041 ms | 3.021 ms | 199.37 MB |

```
public static async Task ReadAll1()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    tasks.Add(File.ReadAllBytesAsync(@"test1.bin"));
    tasks.Add(File.ReadAllBytesAsync(@"test2.bin"));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

```
public static async Task ReadAll2()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => File.ReadAllBytesAsync(@"test1.bin")));
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => File.ReadAllBytesAsync(@"test2.bin")));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: test2.bin is identical to test1.bin

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Yes they are. ReadAllBytesAsync returns a task which is returned to the Task.Run method and are scheduled on the thread pool. Otherwise why would it take 44.55 ms to complete?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov the `Run<TResult> (Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>?>)` overload returns a `Task<TResult>`, not a wrapped task. `Run` automatically unwraps the nested async operation. Without knowing how large the file is we can only guess - my guess is that the file is large enough that the CPU time is due to synchronous buffer allocations

Comment: @user1522446 what are you trying to do with those files? It matters, if you want to improve performance. Instead of allocating 2*100MB in the large object heap it's better to read only what you need, preferably using pooled buffers from eg ArrayPool

Comment: What is the .NET platform where these measurements were made? .NET 7?

Comment: I am using .NET 7

Comment: The platform doesn't matter. You asked the runtime to allocate and then GC a 100GB buffer. That's slow and inherently synchronous. The actual IO is asynchronous but the large buffer allocation isn't. That's why allocating those 2 buffers in parallel is faster than sequential allocations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suspect the difference is due to allocating a big 100MB byte array in the calling thread. `ReadAllBytesAsync` is only meant for small files, precisely because it loads everything in memory. When dealing with large files it's far better to process them line by line or chunk by chunk, preferably using pooled memory.

In `ReadAll1`, each call to `File.ReadAllBytesAsync(@"test1.bin")` allocates a 100MB array then starts an async IO operation to fill it and returns the task to it. This means that the buffers are allocated sequentially in the calling thread.

In `ReadAll2`, `Task.Run(() => File.ReadAllBytesAsync(@"test1.bin"))` allocates the buffer in a background thread before starting the async IO operation.

*Both* options are very inefficient precisely because they allocate 100MB buffers.

---

The `async/await` keywords don't make a method run in the background by magic. Async methods have some part that's inherently asynchronous, eg IO or starting background calls, and some that by necessity synchronous. `await` allows awaiting those truly async operations without blocking the caller.

In `ReadAllBytesAsync` the IO can be asynchronous but allocating the result buffer happens on the calling thread.

[The source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6123cb00bbec8ae3500c970890f5b0efcf7950e8/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/File.cs#L923) shows this. If the file length is known, the entire buffer is allocated at once, while the IO is executed asynchronously :

```
    private static async Task<byte[]> InternalReadAllBytesAsync(SafeFileHandle sfh, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (sfh)
        {
            int index = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[count];
            do
            {
                int n = await RandomAccess.ReadAtOffsetAsync(sfh, bytes.AsMemory(index), index, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (n == 0)
                {
                    ThrowHelper.ThrowEndOfFileException();
                }

                index += n;
            } while (index < count);

            return bytes;
        }
    }
```

That `byte[] bytes = new byte[count];` allocates a 100MB array in a single operation. That's expensive to create *and* expensive to garbage-collect.

Comment: Both approaches use `ReadAllBytesAsync` so wouldn't they end up with the same allocations?

Comment: In one case the allocations run concurrently though due to `Task.Run`

Comment: In the example I posted the 100 MB files are for test purposes to show timing differences.  Actually, I am trying to read four 1 GB files and parse and combine them.  Previously I had tried BinaryReader.ReadBytes() but this is much slower than ReadAllBytesAsync.  Where does it say that ReadAllBytesAsync is for small files?

Comment: The line `new byte[count];`. Programs don't allocate 100MB or 1GB byte buffers intentionally. Everything over 80KB is considered a Large object and allocated from a separate Large Object Heap. Such objects are assumed to be long-lived so the garbage collector clears them only in Gen 2 runs. `I had tried BinaryReader.ReadBytes() but this is much slower than ReadAllBytesAsync.` that's inaccurate, as both read bytes chunk by chunk. Again, what are you trying to do? There are certainly better ways to do it, especially if you want to process 1GB of data

Comment: The why matters. Perhaps you can use methods that accept a stream instead of an entire buffer. Perhaps you can process the data one chunk at a time. Perhaps you can use [memory mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) to treat the large file as a byte array without loading it in memory. Or you may be able to use [System.IO.Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines)

Answer (score 4):

In your second version you are scheduling your tasks to be run on the thread pool, likely resulting in parallell execution. Whereas the first version are likely being executed on the same thread. You can verify it by looking at `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` inside your Task.Run functions.